# Combinations of binary features (vectors)

Tags: algorithm, search, optimization

The source data for the subject is an m-by-n binary matrix (only 0s and 1s are allowed).
m Rows represent observations, n columns - features. Some observations are marked as targets which need to be separated from the rest.

While it looks like a typical NN, SVM, etc problem, I don't need generalization. What I need is an efficient algorithm to find as many as possible combinations of columns (features) that completely separate targets from other observations, classify, that is.

For example:

```
    f1 f2 f3
o1   1  1  0
t1   1  0  1
o2   0  1  1
```

Here {f1, f3} is an acceptable combo which separates target t1 from the rest (o1, o2) (btw, {f2} is NOT as by task definition a feature MUST be present in a target). In other words,

```
t1(f1) & t1(f3) = 1 and o1(f1) & o1(f3) = 0, o2(f1) & o2(f3) = 0
where '&' represents logical conjunction (AND).
```

The m is about 100,000, n is 1,000. Currently the data is packed into 128bit words along m and the search is optimized with sse4 and whatnot. Yet it takes way too long to obtain those feature combos. 
After 2 billion calls to the tree descent routine it has covered about 15% of root nodes. And found about 8,000 combos which is a decent result for my particular application.

I use some empirical criteria to cut off less probable descent paths, not without limited success, but is there something radically better? Im pretty sure there gotta be?.. Any help, in whatever form, reference or suggestion, would be appreciated.

Comment: Clarification request: Suppose you have t1, t2, o1, o2. Will you: a) search once to seperate t1,t2 from o1,o2 b) search twice, one to seperate t1 from o1,o2 and the other to seperate t2 from o1,o2 c) search twice one to seperate t1 from o1,o2,t2 and the other to seperate t2 from o1,o2,t1 ?

Comment: Ali: currently search is done recursively by descending a tree and eliminating already processed combinations so each combo is considered only once.

Comment: I don't understand. Suppose there are three features f1,f2,f3. I'll write these features in binary so i.e. 101 means f1, not f2, f3. Suppose t1=110 t2=101 o1=010 o2=011. Now is {f1} a solution since it seperates t1 and t2 from the rest? Or do we need two different solutions, s1={f1,f2} to seperate t1 and s2={f1,f3} to seperate t2 ?

Comment: Ali: i see what you mean. i dint want to pollute my question with additional details but that made it unclear, i guess. the actual task requires to find any f-combo that separates at least a certain number of targets from the rest. 
suppose, this number say, mint, is 1.
then in your example, f1 is a solution.
it would still be if there was a t3=001 or t2 was not separated. 
but if mint =3, then f1 in your example would not be a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you describe is NP-Hard so you shouldn't expect to find the optimum solution in a reasonable time. I do not understand your current algorithm, but here are some suggestions on the top of my head:

1) Construct a decision tree. Label targets as A and non-targets as B and let the decision tree learn the categorization. At each node select the feature such that a function of P(target | feature) and P(target' | feature') is maximum. (i.e. as many targets as possible fall to positive side and as many non-targets as possible fall to negative side)

2) Use a greedy algorithm. Start from the empty set and at each time step add the feauture that kills the most non-target rows.

3) Use a randomized algorithm. Start from a small subset of positive features of some target, use the set as the seed for the greedy algorithm. Repeat many times. Pick the best solution. Greedy algorithm will be fast so it will be ok.

4) Use a genetic algorithm. Generate random seeds for the greedy algorithm  as in 3 to generate good solutions and cross-product them (bitwise-and probably) to generate new candidates seeds. Remember the best solution. Keep good solutions as the current population. Repeat for many generations.

You will need to find the answer "how many of the given rows have the given feature f" fast so probably you'll need specialized data structures, perhaps using a BitArray for each feature.

Comment: will you not answer your question and tell about the linear time algorithm you found?